# How to multi select in matrix of SAP B1?

Tags: sdk, sapb1

I created UDO which has matrix in SAP B1 and I used UDV (UDV of query which selects all Items code) in first column in order to select all items code, so in matrix of UDO it's impossible to choose from list more than one Item, except to select one by one.

How can I choose from list more than one item in matrix of UDO?

I tried to use below codes but there's an issue.

I tried to see in all examples of matrix in SDK sample but there is no example which can solve my issue, even here in the portal, there is no one who solved this issue.

Is there someone who can help me please?

```
Private Sub SBO_Application_ItemEvent(ByVal FormUID As String, ByRef pVal As SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent, ByRef BubbleEvent As Boolean) Handles SBO_Application.ItemEvent
    If pVal.BeforeAction AndAlso pVal.EventType = SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_FORM_LOAD AndAlso pVal.FormTypeEx = "UDO_FT_RLPY" Then
        Dim oForm As SAPbouiCOM.Form = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID)
        Dim oMatrix As SAPbouiCOM.Matrix
        oMatrix = oForm.Items.Item("C_0_1").Specific 'ISSUE IS HERE, to this line (C_0_1 is the Unique ID of first column of matrix, I do know well if it is that I have to use there because it brings error)
        If pVal.Modifiers = SAPbouiCOM.BoModifiersEnum.mt_SHIFT Then
            Dim lastRowSelected As Integer = oMatrix.Rows.SelectedRows.Item(oMatrix.Rows.SelectedRows.Count - 1, SAPbouiCOM.BoOrderType.ot_RowOrder)
            If lastRowSelected < pVal.Row Then
                For i As Integer = pVal.Row To lastRowSelected + 1
                    oMatrix.Rows.SelectedRows.Add(i)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: So old and probably already in production but what about `oMatrix.SelectionMode = BoMatrixSelect.ms_Auto;` on form load to override systems settings?
This is on C# but similar in VB

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop and after adding one row use AddRow method an so on..

From SDK Help

```
Public Sub AddRow( _
   Optional ByVal RowCount As Long = 1, _
   Optional ByVal Position As Long = -1 _
)
```

Comment: Hi blatsabidze, I edited my question in order to explain well what I want to do. Thank you